# reference to ODC in excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create a reference to an .odc file in Excel. 
(the actual connection string is saved in that .odc file). 
So a file path(root/trusted domains/connections or something) and a file name will be entered.
The idea is to upload the excel to, say SharePoint, and have a pivot table automatically refresh data from the source. I am using c#.

Should i use OpenXML or Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop?
Does anyone have an example of any sort? I'm no expert in XML(reading, writing, where to look).

Comment: Update: I unzipped a random .xlsx file that has an dataconnection referention, i found connections.xml in there. So now the only trick is to unzip,edit and re-zip the .xlsx file to add the connection!